# How to use Qt on another project in Visual Studio once it is already working on one project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I am new to C++ and Qt and I am supporting a project using it. Someone set up my Visual C++ environment with Qt. I wanted to start another test project for me to practice with C++ and Qt. Ive created a new C++ project in Visual Studio, but I have no idea how to add the Qt library to it. There is a Qt menu item at the top of Visual Studio. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select new project in VisualStudio (SHIFT+CTRL+N) you should see Qt4 Projects tab to your left. Select it and then select the type of Qt project you want create. Most likely you would be needing a "QtApplication" or "Qt Console Application" . When you create an application this way, you will have all Qt libraries and includes setup by the Qt-VS Addin automatically

The Qt menu on the top means that you already have a Qt-VisualStudio add-in installed.