# error with Qt libraries in visual c++ application

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I am working with a Qt based project in visual c++. Initially I installed Qt 4.7.3 and imported its libraries in visual c++. Everything was working fine. yesterday, I ran "configure" command on command on command prompt. After that I am receiving error messages while compiling the program.

So I uninstalled Qt 4.7.3 and installed 4.7.4 and configured again the libraries. But still I am receiving the same error messages.

> Qwt.lib(moc_qwt_scale_widget.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QWidget::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QWidget@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
>   1>Qwt.lib(moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QLayout::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QLayout@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
>   1>..\Debug\project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
>   1>

Can anyone please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its a linker error.. you need to compile your headers that contain Q_OBJECT macro with moc compiler. Look at this guys solutions

[Q_OBJECT Problem in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272040/q-object-problem-in-visual-c/7272582#7272582)